# How to train ML .Net model in runtime

Tags: ml.net

is there any way to train an ml .net model in runtime through user input?
I've created a text classification model, trained it local, deployed it and now my users are using it.

Needed workflow:

Text will be categorized, category is displayed to user, he can accept it or select another of the predefined categories, than this feedback should train the model again.

Thanks!

Comment: What trainer did you use for your model? You can [retrain the model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/retrain-model-ml-net) but only a few trainers have the capability.

Comment: I think I used the SdcaMaximumEntropyMulticlassTrainer.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing seems like [online learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning).

ML.NET doesn't have any true 'online' models (by which I mean, models that can adapt to new data example by example and instantaneously refresh): all ML.NET algorithms are 'batch' trainers, that require a (typically large) corpus of training data to produce a model.

If your situation allows, you could aggregate the users' responses as 'additional training data', and re-train the model periodically using this data (in addition to the older data, possibly down-sampled or otherwise decayed).

As @Jon pointed out, a slight modification of the above mechanism is to 'incrementally train an existing model on a new batch of data'. This is still a batch method, but it can reduce the retraining time.

Of ML.NET's multiclass trainers, only `LbfgsMaximumEntropyMulticlassTrainer` supports this mode (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/retrain-model-ml-net)).

It might be tempting to take this approach to the limit, and 'retrain' the model on each 'batch' of one example. **Unless you really, really know what you are doing, I would advise against it**: more likely than not, such a training regime will be overfitting rapidly and disastrously.